# How to convert a decimal number to numbers in days, hours, and min in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple cell A2 (48.48333333). I want to convert this number to number of days, numbers of hours, and number of minutes. I expect to see 2 days, and 30 minutes (conversion note: numbers after the decimal (.) would be converted as follow: .50 = 30 minutes, .25 = 15 minutes, .75 = 45 minutes) in this example, .48333333 would be 30 minutes).

Here is my attempts so far but the result is not what I expected.

```
=INT(A2) & " Days " & INT(MOD(A2, INT(A2))*24) & " Hours and " & MINUTE(A2) & " Minutes"
=TEXT(A2, "d \d, h\hr, m \m")
```

Is there a link or method in Excel that I can convert A2 cell into days, hours, and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INT(A2/24) & "d " & TEXT(A2/24,"h\h m\m")
```

[image]

Comment: @ForwardEd yup back to the grind

Comment: Scott I was just looking at [the formatting/mask options for use under the TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) and it does not list \h or \m.  I can see that the \ is making TEXT take the next letter as text and not a variable.  Do you know where the documentation on this "Trick" is?

Comment: @ForwardEd ``\`` is the escape character - same in custom number formatting, as noted [here](https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats).

Comment: @BigBen thanks for that link.  Much appreciated.   The hard part is remembering all this stuff when you need and only needing it a couple of times a year.

Comment: @ForwardEd I completely agree, I have to do a refresher every time I want a custom format.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job **ONLY if the total hour is less than 768 (or 32 days)** as being pointed out by @ForwardEd:

```
=TEXT(A1/24,"d\d h\h m\m")
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: what happens when the number of hours is 32 days or more?

Comment: @ForwardEd good point :] never knew there was a rounding issue of `32` in the date and time in excel. Have edited my solution accordingly. Tks!

Comment: the reason being is it is just pulling the day of the month. After you pass 31 day or rather hit 32 you are on the 1 st day of February.  1 represents 1900/01/01.  What Scott's answer was doing was pulling the number of days out separately so as not to be confused as a date.  So its not really a rounding error, more of what is being represented by d.

Answer (score 0):

OK I know this is old, but if someone found this looking for the answer as I did. Here is what you can do.

If you have decimal value in days. i.e 52.85385614
Which is: 52 days, 20 hours, 29 minutes, 33.171 seconds, you need to use a formula to format it. (value in cell B7, formula in cell C7)

```
=CONCAT(INT(B7),".",TEXT(B7-TRUNC(B7),"hh:mm:ss.000"))
```

This will produce a value of: 52.20:29:33.171